# Is there a way to disable transparency on the keyboard in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios7

I would like to have a keyboard with a non-transparent keyboard - I couldn't get this with any of the supported UIKeyboardTypes. Is there another way around this?

I suppose I could just overlay a background view under the keyboard with the color I want - would there be a good way to animate that background view in sync with the keyboard show animation?

Answer (score 5):

The keyboard in iOS7 is translucent when app is compiled in Xcode 5 with a Base SDK of iOS 7.
If you build the app on Xcode 4.6.x instead, you'll have the non-translucent keyboard as before.
(i know this is a shitty fix but nonetheless, i thought i'd suggest it)

anyways, you could alternatively try making use of the default keyboard notifications:

1. `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`
2. `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`

should go something like:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}
```

---

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note
{
    /*
     Would have used:
     CGRect rectStart = [note.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
     CGRect rectEnd = [note.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

     Reason for not using:
     The above two keys are not being used although, ideally, they should have been
     since they seem to be buggy when app is in landscape mode

     Resolution:
     Using the deprecated UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey since it works more efficiently
     */

    CGRect rectStart_PROPER = [note.userInfo[UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    rectStart_PROPER.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;

    UIView *vwUnderlay = [self.view viewWithTag:8080];
    if (vwUnderlay) {
        [vwUnderlay removeFromSuperview];
    }

    vwUnderlay = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [vwUnderlay setFrame:rectStart_PROPER];
    [vwUnderlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    [vwUnderlay setTag:8080];
    [self.view addSubview:vwUnderlay];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]
                          delay:0
                        options:[note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue] << 16
                     animations:^{
                         [vwUnderlay setFrame:CGRectOffset(vwUnderlay.frame, 0, -vwUnderlay.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

---

```
-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIView *vwUnderlay = [self.view viewWithTag:8080];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:[note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]
                          delay:0
                        options:[note.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue] << 16
                     animations:^{
                         [vwUnderlay setFrame:CGRectOffset(vwUnderlay.frame, 0, vwUnderlay.frame.size.height)];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [vwUnderlay removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of overhead and fairly temperamental if Apple decides to change anything in iOS 7.1 or iOS 8. Clever though.

Comment: @KyleClegg : true but i don't see any other way. Plus... it doesn't matter if they even change anything about the keyboard because well... it's a `UIView`

Comment: Yeah. Good that you're using the kbFrame too and not just hardcoding the frame - might be useful if the form factor changes again with the iPhone 6.

Comment: it does not make your code bad, but working with no block-based animations is so yesterday (since iOS4), and the setting up the notification center with blocks would be better practice as well. a little modernisation won't hurt at all, regarding iOS4 was relased precisely 4 years ago by now.

Comment: @holex : yes, it is so yesterday especially since the solution was designed for iOS7. i'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow anyone to modify the default keyboard. If you are going to be using iOS 7 then you will have to deal with the translucent keyboard.

The only other way I can think of is designing your own keyboard, but that's a tedious process to go through.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the same thing today, and I found a simple workaround (although, not yet sure how reliable it is).

In order to work, I've set up an `inputAccessoryView` for my keyboard controls (`UITextView` and `UITextField`). In the `UIView` class that I've set as the `inputAccessoryView` I added the followings:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    frame = _lKeyboardBackground.frame;
    frame.origin.y = [self convertPoint:self.frame.origin toView:self.superview].y+self.frame.size.height;
    frame.size.width = self.bounds.size.width;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.size.height = 500;
    _lKeyboardBackground.frame = frame;

    [self refreshKeyboardBackground];
}
-(void)didMoveToSuperview{
    [super didMoveToSuperview];
    if (self.superview) {
        [self.superview.layer insertSublayer:_lKeyboardBackground atIndex:lMagicLayerIndex];
    }
    else {
        [_lKeyboardBackground removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
}
-(void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    [super setFrame:frame];
    [self refreshKeyboardBackground];  // setFrame: is called when keyboard changes (e.g: to a custom input view)
}
-(void)refreshKeyboardBackground{
    if (_lKeyboardBackground.superlayer) {
        CALayer *parent = _lKeyboardBackground.superlayer;
        [_lKeyboardBackground removeFromSuperlayer];
        [parent insertSublayer:_lKeyboardBackground atIndex:lMagicLayerIndex];
    }
}
```

`_lKeyboardBackground` is a `CALayer` that I've setup in the init methods:

```
_lKeyboardBackground = [CALayer layer];
_lKeyboardBackground.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor]; //or some less annoying color
```

This should theoretically pass Apple's approval, but I never tested. There's also plenty of changes this will not work in future versions, or in some other situations (e.g when there's a split keyboard on the iPad)

`lMagicLayerIndex` that I use is 1, which gives the absolute color.
Note that the blur can still be noticed on key-strokes.

Answer (score 0):

Use keyboard notification to show/hide a custom black view behind the keyboard (or white if you use the white keyboard) and voila, transparent no more.