# How to display UIView from bottom of the iPad screen like in the Evernote App

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiview

[image]I try to display in my app simple `UIView` by clicking on a `UIBarButton`. I want to display it from the bottom of the screen with an animation like the one in in Evernote app.

Which class should I use? If anyone has seen simple tutorial, please share it with me.

Comment: Don't expect us to know, or go have a look at the animation you want in Evernote app. Add a screen shot or video.

Comment: Sorry for the inaccurate description of the problem. I would be gratefull for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `UIView` object. Put all the required `subView`'s in it (the "cancel", "save", "title" yada yada)

Add this view as a subView onto the main viewController at the y coordinate: `self.view.frame.size.height`

Then, on the `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`, you can animate it to a different y coordinate by simply changing this `UIView`'s `origin.y` within the animation block.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19678064/2857130
*(you'll need to make the appropriate adaptations to fit your requirement)*

Comment: Ok it works fine for me but how can I display it as a subview of splitViewController? I'm doing it  like that: [self. addSubview: uiview] . Should I display it  in the masterViewController or in detailsViewCOntroller?. How can I fix it . I need to display it in the same way like UIPopoverController  that covers both: masterViewController and detailsViewController . Do you have some ideas how to do that?

Comment: Ok I got it :) [self.splitviewController addSubview: UIView]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a `UIView` placed nicely above the keyboard. Check out this [Github project](https://github.com/simonbs/BSKeyboardControls) that does something similar.